# Setting border-bottom/top-right/left-radii

Tags: html, css

I'm editing a page in Chrome with "Inspect element" to make style edits before commiting to my CSS stylesheet.

I'm editing a `:before` pseudo-element on a list to show a hashtag symbol with a green background, and had it looking like a leaf for a second, but upon saving the changes exactly as entered in the preview they're not being displayed on loading the page.

Screenshot of what I saved:                                                               and what I got:
[image]                                                  [image]

Basically the `border-top-left-radius` and `border-bottom-right-radius` were on zero by default, but setting

```
border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
border-top-left-radius: 50px;
```

allowed me to get that effect. I thought at first perhaps the browser had changed its values for `border-top-right` and `border-bottom-left` but declaring these as zero didn't change things. I understand that what you see with the inspect tool isn't always what's actually computed though.

The relevant CSS is

```
content: " ＃";
opacity: 1;
border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
border-top-left-radius: 50px;
text-shadow: #175F0A 1px 1px 0px;
margin-right: 11px;
color: #fff;
background: #81B681;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: center;
border-radius: 28px;
padding-left: 6px;
padding-right: 7px;
padding-top: 4px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
line-height: 2;
border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
border-top-right-radius: 0px;
```

**Update** This is odd - I've [made a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Y4nY/) and it's retaining my style... Guessing I've contradicted somewhere, looking now unless anyone can spot it?

http://jsfiddle.net/6Y4nY/3

Final, working version http://jsfiddle.net/6Y4nY/4

Comment: Can you give jsfiddle link?

Comment: Woahhh what are the odds ! Thanks Josh, weird…
Also yeah 1 sec Nikita

Comment: Okay this seems to be spot on I think, http://jsfiddle.net/WdtVu/1/.

Comment: Cleaned all the garbage out, bare bones jsfiddle now in updated description

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get that shape, you have to set

```
.test {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    background-color: green;
    border-radius: 100% 0px;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tVdTh/)

Since there seems to be confusion about the radius in percentages: border-radius: 50%; gives you a circle.

Any value higher than that must be paired with a lower that 50% "on the other side" to be effective.

If I don't set the second (and fourth) corner to 0px, I can't get the 100% in the first and third

Comment: Do you have to add the 0 to `border-radius` to get that? With just 100% you get a circle, http://jsfiddle.net/tVdTh/1/. I have always wondered why just 100% seem to do nothing.

Comment: @JoshPowell border-radius isn't doing what you think it is... This diagram does an ok job of explaining why... http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/corner.png. Also, Lea Verou did an awesome presentation about it. http://lea.verou.me/humble-border-radius

Comment: Thank you so much for those links! I am checking the presentation out right now.

Comment: Yup, `border-radius: 100% 0px;` was what I needed. Thanks vals!

Answer (score 0):

When I run that code through a fiddle, it comes out like what you want.
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L6xeA/)

```
.test {
content: " ＃";
opacity: 1;
border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
border-top-left-radius: 50px;
text-shadow: #175F0A 1px 1px 0px;
margin-right: 11px;
color: #fff;
background: #81B681;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: center;
border-radius: 28px;
padding-left: 6px;
padding-right: 7px;
padding-top: 4px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
line-height: 2;
border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
border-top-right-radius: 0px;
    display: inline;
}
```

Maybe somewhere else in your code, you are setting the top-right and bottom-left radii as something other than 0?

(I added the display at the bottom to keep the div from taking the whole line)